# How to align items to top inside VStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I just started with swiftui and I am facing issues in ui alignment. The following code creates a space from top of the image

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Image(item.imageUrl)
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(width: 72, height: 72, alignment: .top).padding(.top,0)
        Text("\(item.name)").font(Font.system(size:12, design: .default))
             .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
             .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).lineLimit(2)    
        }
}
```

I can see that VStack accepts param `alignment` , but it's horizontal alignment. What I need is that the Image should stick to the top of its superview.
Is there a way to do this without the use of Spacer().

Like in react-native we used to have justifyContent and alignItems for both horizontal and vertical alignment of children.

UPDATE:

The same issue exists for Text too, or any view.
E.g.  This code places the two text in center of the view

```
 VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text("line 1")
        Text("line 2")
 }
```

[image]

The param alignment in VStack is for horizontal alignment.

Now to align these texts to top, the only way I can think of is by introducing `Spacer()` like this:

```
struct MyCustomView:View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
      Text("line 1")
      Text("line 2")
      Spacer()
    }
 }
```

This does solves the problem temporarily:

[image]

But the spacer will create problem in complex views, lets say another developer wants to add a custom view (line 3 in this case) just below my view, the spacer will create additional space in between

```
VStack {
     MyCustomView()
     Text("line 3")
 }
```

[image]

Is there a better way that my child views (and subsequent views) inside a VStack remains aligned to top without the spacer?

Comment: VStack tights to content, so I don't think it is alignment issue, at least in provided code. Could you give more code context and show screenshot? I would be better if you provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Above code is fine.. there is no space at the top. Where is the VStack wrapped inside?

Comment: @Asperi Updated my question, can you please check

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can try using `.frame()` modifier to make the `VStack()` take full size in it superview. In frame you can align your content `topLeading`

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text("line 1")
        Text("line 2")
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    .border(Color.red)
}
```

No Spacer needed for that solution

[image]

Comment: They want to align sub-views in center.

Comment: @mahan Line1 and line2 should be centered? But still at the top right?

Comment: @davidev thanks man, the alignment param here is of type 'Alignment'  (instead of HorizontalAlignment as in the case of VStack) which accept value for both horizontal and vertical alignment, eg. .top, .center, .topLeading etc.

Answer (score 12):

This works too.

```
 VStack {

          Text("line 1")
          Text("line 2")

    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, // Full Screen Width
            maxHeight: .infinity, // Full Screen Height
            alignment: .topLeading) // Align To top
```

Comment: This worked the best for me

Answer (score 5):

SwiftUI views are cheap. Use another **VStack()** with **Spacer()**.

```
    VStack {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
          Text("line 1")
          Text("line 2")
          // Add your Views here
        }
        Spacer()
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
        
        Text("Default Alignment in Vstack is Center")
        
        VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
            Text(".trailing")
                .font(.title)
            Image(systemName: "rectangle.trailinghalf.inset.filled.arrow.trailing")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Alignment set by .trailing")
            
        }.padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.yellow))
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Text(".leading")
                .font(.title)
            
            Image(systemName: "rectangle.leadinghalf.inset.filled.arrow.leading")
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("Alignment set by .leading")
            
        }.padding()
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).foregroundColor(.yellow))
        
    }
```

[image]