# How to align text to the top of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm looking how to align text to the top of screen, do you know how to?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RegisterSignInScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome Back!")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
            
            
            Text("Please sign in to your account")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct RegisterSignInScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        RegisterSignInScreen()
    }
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL7uA.png)

I tried to embed my `VStack` in a `ZStack`:

`ZStack(alignment: .top)`

But it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want to align both Text elements to the top of the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align items to top inside VStack in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356584/how-to-align-items-to-top-inside-vstack-in-swiftui)

Comment: have you tried adding a `Spacer()` after the `Text("Please sign in to your account")`

Answer (score 1):

To see why this is happening you can add a background to your VStack or ZStack

```
ZStack {
  VStack {
    //Text items
  }
}
.background(.red)
```

What you will notice (maybe unexpectedly) is that the stack is only as big as it needs to be to contain the text items.

When you add alignment to the stack it aligns the content within the stack to the specified edge of the relatively small stack. It doesn't align the stack to an edge of the screen, or change the size of the stack. What you're actually looking to do is align the stack, not it's content.

In order to align to the top of the screen you can make the stack fill the entire height of the screen. Either by adding a `Spacer()` at the bottom of the VStack that will fill the remaining vertical space pushing the content upwards, or by applying a `frame` with `.infinity` `maxHeight:` and top aligned content to the VStack.

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello World!")
    Spacer()
}

VStack {
    Text("Hello World!")
}
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
```

Alternatively if required for your view, you can do a similar thing with a second stack containing your text stack like so:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        welcomeText
        Spacer()
    }
}

var welcomeText: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Welcome Back!")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
        
        
        Text("Please sign in to your account")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a couple of ways, but the most obvious way is to simply add a `Spacer()` in the bottom of the `VStack`

Like so:

```
struct RegisterSignInScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome Back!")    
            Text("Please sign in to your account")

            Spacer() // <- HERE
        }
    }
}
```

This will push your content in the `VStack` to the top.

Alternatively, you can add a frame modifier and force your `VStack` height and add the alignment there using `.frame`

```
struct RegisterSignInScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Welcome Back!")
            Text("Please sign in to your account")
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top) // <- HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZStack(alignment: .top)` works, but not the same way as you think)

try to do:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top){ 

}
.background(Color.green)
```

and you will understand why so :)

you need to use spacer :)

```
VStack {
    YourView()
    Spacer()
}
```